# MSAL 2.0 Bearer token invalid

Tags: jwt, azure-ad-msal, hapi, jwk

I'm trying to upgrade out current MSAL 1.4 auth strategy to MSAL 2.0

I can successfully login and get an Access token using `msal-browser`, however when I try pass that to our backend as a `Bearer Token` I get an `Invalid Token` error.

Our current backend uses `Hapi.js` and `jwks-rsa` to get a list of Keys from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys and I think this is where the issue lies.

Looking at the AccessToken on jwt.io the `x5t` and `kid` values do not match the publicly listed values. Which as I understand it means the two keys will not authenticate.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a scope for your `API` inside the Azure Portal then create `API` permission with the newly created scope. The access token successfully decoded by `hapi-auth-jwt` after which you should do another internal level of authentication inside the `enter validate()` function to return `isValid`: true if the internal auth returned correct results.